# Vague SQL error... what's going on here?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm getting an error from MySQL which is about the most useless error message I've ever seen:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (userID, tweetID),
FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES User(' at line 4
```

Great, check the manual... >*_*_>

Here's the SQL source; I'm sure it will be exceedingly simple to anyone familiar with SQL, but I'm a newb. To me it all looks fine.

I'd really like to have a more well-formed question than "what's my error," but with an error message so vague, and me having so little experience, I'm pretty much lost.

```
CREATE TABLE User (
    username        VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
    userID          INTEGER         NOT NULL,
    fullName        VARCHAR(100),
    passwordHash    VARCHAR(256)    NOT NULL,
    email           VARCHAR(256)    NOT NULL,
    imageURL        VARCHAR(200),
    facebookURL     VARCHAR(200),
    tagline         VARCHAR(140),
    memberSince     TIMESTAMP       NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (userID)
);

CREATE TABLE Tweet (
    tweetID INTEGER                 NOT NULL,
    userID INTEGER                  NOT NULL,
    content VARCHAR(140)            NOT NULL,
    TIMESTAMP                       NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (tweetID),
    FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES User(userID)
);

CREATE TABLE HashTag (
    tweetID INTEGER                 NOT NULL,
    content VARCHAR(140)            NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (content),
    FOREIGN KEY (tweetID) REFERENCES Tweet(tweetID)
);

CREATE TABLE Follows (
    follower INTEGER                NOT NULL,
    followee INTEGER                NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (follower, followee),
    FOREIGN KEY (follower) REFERENCES User(userID),
    FOREIGN KEY (followee) REFERENCES User(userID)
);

CREATE TABLE Retweets (
    tweetID INTEGER                 NOT NULL,
    userID INTEGER                  NOT NULL,
    TIMESTAMP                       NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (userID, tweetID),
    FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES User(userID),
    FOREIGN KEY (tweetID) REFERENCES Tweet(tweetID)
);

CREATE TABLE Mentions (
    tweetID INTEGER                 NOT NULL,
    userID INTEGER                  NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (tweetID, userID),
    FOREIGN KEY (tweetID) REFERENCES Tweet(tweetID),
    FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES User(userID)
);

CREATE TABLE Favorites (
    tweetID INTEGER                 NOT NULL,
    userID INTEGER                  NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (tweetID, userID),
    FOREIGN KEY (tweetID) REFERENCES Tweet(tweetID),
    FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES User(userID)
);

CREATE TABLE CanSee (
    tweetID INTEGER                 NOT NULL,
    userID INTEGER                  NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (tweetID, userID),
    FOREIGN KEY (tweetID) REFERENCES Tweet(tweetID),
    FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES User(userID)
);

CREATE TABLE Message (
    messageID INTEGER               NOT NULL,
    senderID INTEGER                NOT NULL,
    receiverID INTEGER              NOT NULL,
    content VARCHAR(140)            NOT NULL,
    TIMESTAMP                       NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (messageID),
    FOREIGN KEY (senderID) REFERENCES User(userID),
    FOREIGN KEY (receiverID) REFERENCES User(userID)
);
```

Comment: `TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,` you might want to address this one

Answer (score 3):

When it says "NEAR **__**" it's saying that something right before that point triggered an error.

In this case, that's the word `TIMESTAMP`. You listed the `TIMESTAMP` type for that column, but never gave it a name. Perhaps that should be `modified_on TIMESTAMP` (or something to that effect).

Comment: Ah, that would be it. Thanks a lot! Definitely appreciated.